# Labeling roads independent of the scale

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have the problem, that my labelled roads (name of the roads) changes when I also change my scale by zooming in or out. 
But I want a fixed size and position of the street names independent from the scale. 
How can I get to this?

I know there is a possibility to set a X and Y coordinate for each label, but I have really a lot of streets and labels and I want to do this with a rule-based labelling. 
So in a perfect way, I just do the rule-based labelling and my street names have a fix position and size.

Comment: Use data-defined settings to control the label placement based on an expression. Define the X and Y coordinate with the `$x` and `$y` functions if it's a point, or `x($centroid)` and `y($centroid)` if it's a line or polygon.